# Prevent mathematica from simplifying

Tags: formatting

How can i prevent *Mathematica* from automatically simplifying the expression `Sqrt[a/b]`?

In
case `a=1` and `b=2`, *Mathematica* will print `1/Sqrt[2]`, whereas 
case `a=3` and `b=4`, *Mathematica* will print `Sqrt[3/4]`.

The output of my program would be better readable, if the fractions stayed unsimplified under the square-root symbol.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html) and a custom head, e.g. `mySqrt`, along with [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html):

```
Format[mySqrt[body_]] := Sqrt @ HoldForm @ body
```

Now:

```
mySqrt /@ {1/2, 3/4}
```

[image]

If you want to use these expressions as live input (where this  holding behavior will not be preserved) you should use [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpretation.html):

```
Format[mySqrt[body_]] := Interpretation[Sqrt @ HoldForm @ body, Sqrt @ body]
```